# Getting List index out of range, python generator misunderstanding

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given this:

```
class DataFromBls:
    """this is a spitout of data in BLS dump"""

    def __init__(self, dataSource, yearOfData, inflationAdjusted):
        self.dataSource = dataSource
        self.yearOfData = yearOfData
        self.inflationAdjusted = inflationAdjusted

    def printData(self):
        for value in self.dataSource:
            yield self.dataSource[value]
```

Assume then that `x = DataFromBls([2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7], 2010, "yes")`

And then assume that the following was given to the interpreter,

```
for value in x.printData():
    print value
```

Then I get the interpreter spits out 5, 6, 7 and then gives me a Traceback IndexError:list index out of range

I don't understand how its out of range or why only 5 through 7 out

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a close look at what each iteration looks like for the following loop:

```
for value in self.dataSource:
    yield self.dataSource[value]
```

Assuming that `self.dataSource` is the list `[2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7]`:

- 1st iteration:  `value` will be `2`,    `self.dataSource[2]` will be the 3rd element, or `5`
- 2nd iteration: `value` will be `3`,    `self.dataSource[3]` will be the 4th element, or `6`
- 3rd iteration:  `value` will be `5`,    `self.dataSource[5]` will be the 6th element, or `7`
- 4th iteration:  `value` will be `6`,    `self.dataSource[6]` causes the `IndexError`

Your issue is that you are looping directly over the elements in the list, not indices.  You want to do one of the following:

```
for value in self.dataSource:
    yield value
```

Or...

```
for i in range(len(self.dataSource)):
    yield self.dataSource[i]
```

Obviously the first method is preferred, the second just illustrates how you can get the indices if that is what you need.

Note that on Python 3.3 and above, you can just use `yield from self.dataSource` to get the same behavior as `for value in self.dataSource: yield value`.

Answer (score 1):

The next element is `6`, and `self.dataSource[6]` is out of bounds (the last element is `self.dataSource[5]`).

Did you mean to write:

```
def printData(self):
    for value in self.dataSource:
        yield value
```

?

Comment: Ah crap, yep that was it. Should have just said `value`